# Calling an AS function with ExternalInterface.call() injected JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I call a function in ActionScript 3 from JavaScript that has been injected into the page using `ExternalInterface.call()`?

I've tried this a bunch of ways, to no avail.

Here is a simplified version of all the necessary code:

```
public function myClass() {

    ExternalInterface.addCallback("callASFunction", myASFunction);

    var loadJS:XML =
    <script><![CDATA[

        function(oid){

            ob = document.getElementById(oid);

            if (!window.FB) { /* Include FB JS SDK */ }

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

                FB.init({ ... });

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                 /* ob.callASFunction(); <= ERROR */
                    ob.callASFunction(response.status); /* <= FIX */
                });
            }
        }

    ]]></script>

    // Inject the JS into the page
    ExternalInterface.call(loadJS, ExternalInterface.objectID);

}

public function myASFunction(vars:String){

    // Do great things

}
```

### **Comments**

The line marked with `<= ERROR` throws the following in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

And in FF:

```
uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.
```

I believe that the issue is that the `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` is not attaching a listener on the Flash object before the `ob.callASFunction()` is called.

Or, perhaps I'm missing something.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible fixes to this.

**Don't force a parameter for the called AS method**

```
public function myASFunction(vars:String = null){ ... }
```

or

**Always pass a variable to the method**

```
ob.callASFunction(response.status); /* <= FIX */
```

Bit of a facepalm moment.
:{D

---

Note: I've edited my answer to reflect the JS fix, but not the AS one.